# Android Developer - Updating an App Published in the Market

Tags: android, google-play

Prior to publishing my app on the market I could connect my phone via USB and run/debug the app on the phone (signed with development key). Now that I have published it on the market I find that in order to run it on my phone I have to export a signed apk and copy it to my phone's SD card and then install it. This is a hassle but even worse is that I can no longer run the app in debug mode on my phone. I have not seen anyone else complain about this so I presume I am lacking some understanding of the process. Can anyone help?

Thanks
aussieW

Comment: Have you tried just uninstalling the app fully and then trying to debug?

Comment: The problem is that the app stores info in a database, so if I uninstall the app I loose the info in the database.

Comment: Oh i see what does your logcat say when you try to debug? And your database dtrying to duplicate may be the issue.

Comment: Logcat doesn't show any errors but the Console Log does show the following: "Re-installation failed due to different application signatures" and "You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!"

Answer (score 1):

This means that you will need to uninstall the current application on the device in order to debug.

Comment: Okay, I just wish there was an easier way to keep developing/debugging once an app has been put on the market.

Comment: Well thats why most people us a seperate debug device. So it wont interfere with there market application's on there real device

Answer (score 1):

I just do a "run" from Eclipse as usual to debug, and I didn't need to sign anything, only when exporting the file to be published. I don't put the file manually in the phone; I have a run configuration that runs the app right on the phone via USB DEBUGGING. The catch is I can't have USB Storage AND Debugging on at the same time.